# Why the data type of :'variable' in psql is unknown?

Tags: psql

Store `2024-01-01` in variable mydate:

```
\set mydate '2024-01-01'
```

Call it:

```
\echo  :mydate
2024-01-01
\echo  :'mydate'
'2024-01-01'
```

Check data type:

```
select pg_typeof(:mydate);
 pg_typeof 
-----------
 integer
(1 row)

Time: 0.379 ms
select pg_typeof(:'mydate');
 pg_typeof 
-----------
 unknown
```

Why `pg_typeof(:'mydate')` is unknown type?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

“Data type” is a matter of SQL, but your variable is a `psql` variable. `psql` variables have no data type, they are all strings. When you use the variable in an SQL statement, `psql` replaces the variable with its value *before* sending the statement to the server.

All that the server sees is a plain string literal, and the internal type of that is `unknown`:

```
SELECT pg_typeof('string');
 pg_typeof 
═══════════
 unknown
(1 row)
```

Data of type `unknown` get converted to the appropriate type based on context:

```
-- here, PostgreSQL deduces the type "text"
SELECT 'some' || 'string';

  ?column?  
════════════
 somestring
(1 row)

-- here, PostgreSQL deduces type "integer" and throws an error
SELECT 'some' + 1;
ERROR:  invalid input syntax for type integer: "some"
LINE 1: SELECT 'some' + 1;
               ^
```